# Rewriting AR model in State-Space form

Tags: time-series, kalman-filter, state-space-models

How can I rewrite an AR(p) model in state-space form?
Max(p)=5 and I want to use Kalman Predictor.

Comment: May I ask what kind of data do you want to model and for what usage you want to do it?

Comment: Turbulent velocity components (3D) collected by an HR Acoustic Doppler Current Profiler (HRCP) in an estuary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you buy the excellent book by G. Petris, S. Petrone and P. Campagnoli [Dynamic Linear Models with R](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-77237-0).

You will learn that any ARMA model

$Y_t = \sum_{j=1}^{r}\phi_jY_{t-j} + \sum_{j=1}^{r-1}\psi_{j}\epsilon_t$

can be expressed in the following form:

$  
\begin{matrix}  
Y_t & = & F\theta_t\\     
\theta_{t+1} & = & G\theta_{t}+R\epsilon_t  
\end{matrix}  $

with
$
F=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & ... & 0
\end{bmatrix}  
$

$
G=\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_1 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0\\ 
\phi_2 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0\\ 
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
\phi_{r-1} & 0 & ... & 0 & 1\\ 
\phi_r & 0 & ... & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}  
$

$
R={\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \psi_1 & ... & \psi_{r-2} & \psi_{r-1}
\end{bmatrix}}'
$

In your specific case, just set $r=5$ and $\psi_{j=1..5}=0$.
You can use the package [dlm](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/web/packages/dlm/index.html) to use the Kalman filter on this model.

Comment: Where can I find help to display the latex formulae!

Comment: Surround latex with `$ .. $`

Comment: Thanks fRed, first part is quite useful, but as this calculation is a part of much larger code, I cannot use dlm unless it can be linked with Mathematica Kernel.

Comment: You can use http://www.scienceops.com/Rlink2.asp
But too bad you have to pay to use R!

Answer (score 4):

Another good book that covers this is [Time Series Analysis by State Space Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198523548) by Durbin and Koopman (pp 46-49.)